# How to select last row of each hour in a day?

Tags: mysql

From MySQL database, I want to get all last rows of each hour in a day, the table look like this,

`Id  Name  Vcum   Date         Time
------------------------------------------

1   A     5.5    2014-11-20   09:00

2   B     4.3    2014-11-20   09:05

3   A     6.7    2014-11-20   09:10

4   C     5.9    2014-11-20   09:10

5   A     7.2    2014-11-20   09:20

6   C     6.5    2014-11-20   09:25

7   B     8.1    2014-11-20   09:30

8   C     9.4    2014-11-20   09:35

9   A     6.5    2014-11-20   10:05

10  A     8.1    2014-11-20   10:28

11  C     9.5    2014-11-20   10:32

12  B     9.7    2014-11-20   10:36

13  A     8.8    2014-11-20   10:39

14  C     9.8    2014-11-20   10:42

15  B     9.9    2014-11-20   10:42`


Is that possible to get the following result by using sql?

`Id  Name  Vcum   Date         Time

------------------------------------------

5   A     7.2    2014-11-20   09:20 <-- Last row of HOUR(Time) = 9 for Name = A

7   B     8.1    2014-11-20   09:30 <-- Last row of HOUR(Time) = 9 for Name = B

8   C     9.4    2014-11-20   09:35 <-- Last row of HOUR(Time) = 9 for Name = C

13  A     8.8    2014-11-20   10:39 <-- Last row of HOUR(Time) =10 for Name = A

15  B     9.9    2014-11-20   10:42 <-- Last row of HOUR(Time) =10 for Name = B

14  C     9.8    2014-11-20   10:42 <-- Last row of HOUR(Time) =10 for Name = C`

Comment: Is the `Id` column is auto incremented primary key ?

Comment: Yes, it is auto incremented primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Vcum, a.Date, a.Time 
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.Name, a.Date, MAX(a.Time) colTIme 
                FROM tableA a
                GROUP BY a.Name, a.Date
                ) b ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.Date = b.Date AND a.Time = b.colTime
```

Comment: Thanks, the selection part for inner join only return the last rows or say last time of each [Name] in a day, not per hour

Comment: It works if change it into this, <code>SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Vcum, a.Date, a.Time FROM tabkeA a INNER JOIN(
SELECT a.Name, a.Date, MAX(a.Time) aTime
                FROM tabkeA a 
                GROUP BY a.Name, HOUR(a.Time)
) b ON a.Name=b.Name AND a.Date=b.Date AND a.Time=b.aTime</code>, Thanks Shah

Answer (score 0):

hint : you have to do like

```
   select maxTime from tableName group by HOUR
```

this will work i hope so

Comment: Thanks Affan, but if I use group by HOUR then only one name will return for each hour which is not what I want.

Comment: you want last data thats y i write maxTime . if you want to get all data then remove maxData part

Comment: @user2189138 With a couple of minor tweaks, it certainly sounds like what you want !?!

Comment: I know, Affan. Thats will be my last try if I couldn't find any others. Thanks.